# React TS - Can you assign default values to a map()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I currently have a component that maps through an array of data. I'd like to be able to set default values for some of the attributes.

My current `Link` component:

```
const Link: React.FC<ILink> = ({ icons }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {icons.map(item => (
        <a href={item.href} target={item.target} rel={item.rel}>
          {/* Some element */}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Typically using TypeScript, I would destructure the props like so, and then add my defaults:

```
const Link: React.FC<ILink> = ({
  href,
  target = "_blank",
  rel = "noreferrer noopener"
}) => {}
```

How can I do this for my map though?

Comment: Why would it be any different, it's just another arrow function: `icons.map(({ href, target = "_blank", rel = "noreferrer noopener" }) => ...`

Comment: You can also use the `||` operator. `rel={item.rel || "some default"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure and assign defaults the same way in your `map` callback:

```
const Link: React.FC<ILink> = ({ icons }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {icons.map(({ href, target = "_blank", rel = "noreferrer noopener" }) => (
        <a href={href} target={target} rel={rel}>
          {/* Some element */}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Alternately, you can simply use the or-operator to define fallbacks inline if you only expect string values to be passed:

```
const Link: React.FC<ILink> = ({ icons }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {icons.map(item => (
        <a href={item.href} target={item.target || "_blank"} rel={item.rel || "noopener noreferrer"}>
          {/* Some element */}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I'm not sure why I'm getting down votes, I'm still learning and simply didn't know.